# Adding onclick to div element yields "Result of expression 'document.getElementById('elem1')"[null]

Tags: javascript, safari

is not an object" in the safari browser. The entire code is

```
function addLinks () {
    var p0 = document.getElementById('Pic0').onclick = addLinkAction;
}

function addLinkAction () {
    var el = document.getElementById('vid0');
    el.style.display = "block";
    el.play();
}
```

The functions work fine but safari continues to throw errors when the page is rendered and and on each click of the link. I'm only testing this in safari as it's a HTML5 - iPad/iPhone only media. thanks

Comment: Please post your HTML, and the error message that Safari is giving you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function addLinks () {
  var p0 = document.getElementById('Pic0').onclick = function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('vid0');
    el.style.display = "block";
    el.play();
  }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element exists. When you invoke `addLinks` do it on DOM ready or `window.onload = function(){}`. Alternatively, put the script before the end body tag.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you call function `addLinks()` on document load/ready, try to add return false as last statement of this inner function

```
function addLinks () { 
   var p0 = document.getElementById('Pic0');
   p0.onclick = function() {
      addLinkAction();
      return false;
   } 
}
```